# Validation using the template driven validation

Tags: angular, validation, templates

Using angular5 I am developing an application.I have a list of tags that is displayed and user can change the value and after clicking save that should be updated. I am using template driven validation.Here the problem is that I am giving unique name to each field by appending the increment value `i` (tag{{i}}). But and it is working perfectly. But in case I need to show validation errors at the time of touch , for that the syntax is`formname.form.controls.controlname.errors.required` but I am not able to give the `controlname` directly because I am using incremented value attached string as name. My code so far is,

```html
<form #tagRuleForm="ngForm">
<div class="tables" [dragula]='"tag-bag"'>
<div class="rows" *ngFor="let tagRuleList of tagRulesList; let i = index"  [class.active]="isSelected(tagRuleList.tagRuleId)" >
<div class="cells1">
     <input name="tag{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="tagRuleList.tag"  minlength = "2" maxlength="1000" required >
   <div *ngIf="!tagRuleForm.form.valid && (tagRuleForm.controls.tag{{i}}.touched ||tagRuleForm.controls.tag{{i}}.dirty )"
                  class="alert alert-danger">
     <div *ngIf="tagRuleForm.controls.tag{{i}}.errors.required">
         Field can't be blank
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
    [disabled]="!tagRuleForm.form.valid" (click)="save()"  > 
      Submit
 </button>
</form>
```

How can we do that in case of template driven validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<div *ngIf="tagRuleForm.controls['tag' + i].errors.required">
```

Comment: (Although I don't know if template driven forms rely on names, I trust you on that, I'm just giving your the correct syntax)

Comment: It is not possible

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: It is giving the error `Cannot read property 'required' of null` and the error class is showing on `index0` always

Comment: Then errors doesn't exist, just like I imagined. You can't bind a model from the name only.